# Conditional Operator for React Components, not updating

Tags: javascript, reactjs, if-statement, conditional-statements, state

I currently have 2 Components that work conditionally, but i would like it to update and change
when the createdSavingsGoal state array is greater than 0 (i.e Not empty)

Then it shows a List.. When its empty it shows a Form that allows me to Post to that array.
**Currently i have to refresh that page but i would just like it to work. automatically**

Im not brilliant with State so if im doing something obvious.

```
this.state = {
  createdSavingsGoal: "",
};
```

..

```
render() {
const { createdSavingsGoal } = this.state;
if (createdSavingsGoal.length > 0) {
  return <ViewSavingsGoal />;
} else {
  return <CreateSavingsGoal />;
}
```

Comment: Are you changing the state anywhere?